# jQuery: How to append checkbox to each row in table?

Tags: jquery, append, html-table

I've this for append elements from json:

```
$.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: action,
                data: dataSearch,
                success: function (response) {

                    if (response[0].success == "success") {
                        $.each(response, function (index, record) {
                            var row = $("<tr />");
                            $("<td />").text(record.clavemat).appendTo(row);
                            $("<td />").text(record.tipomat).appendTo(row);
                            $("<td />").text(record.titulomat).appendTo(row);
                            $("<td />").text(record.autormat).appendTo(row);
                            $("<td />").text(record.editmat).appendTo(row);
                            $("<td />").text(record.edicmat).appendTo(row);
                            //Append checkbox to each row
                            row.addClass("alt");
                            row.appendTo(".resultsSearch");
                        });
                    } else {
                        alert("Data not found");
                    }

                }
            });
            return false;
```

And I want append checkbox for each row at last column, and I dont know
Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Have you tried?:

```
$("<td />").html('<input type="checkbox"/>').appendTo(row);
```

And by the way, are you sure that POST is the best choice if you are GETing information from the server? or are you changing the status of the server when you do the request?
If it is not the case, check [When to use Post or Get](http://www.w3.org/2001/tag/doc/whenToUseGet.html)

Comment: After that I add the checkbox... why ignore this function? $('table tr').click(function() {
  check = $(this).children('td').children('input[type=checkbox]');
     
  if (check.attr('checked'))
   check.attr('checked',false);
  else
   check.attr('checked',true);
 }); Is used to check when click on any part of the row is checked the checkbox.

Comment: If you are adding the function at the document.ready moment, it will not work, because the rows are not created yet, you should use .on

Comment: It works :, thanks again! btw, I hope you do not mind that you add to facebook (Edgar Ramirez, SoldierCorp)...Regards!